# How do I replace all files in a folder in SVN, but treat as a normal revision?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

My situation is that I have two tar files containing the source code for a project at different versions. I would like to add the older version of the code to a Subversion server and then replace the source files with the newer ones and re-commit. This way, each source file would have both revisions tracked in SVN and it would be easy to see what all changes were made between the two versions of the code. In particular, the behavior I desire would be equivalent to doing the following:

1. Check in the first version of the code (this is trivial to do, of course.)
2. In the working copy, `svn delete` all files and directories not present in the new version.
3. Copy the code (including all files and directories) of the new version over the old version in the working copy.
4. `svn add` all of the new files and folders.
5. Commit the working copy as if it were a normal commit.

If you happen to have a script that just does the above (ideally a bash script,) that would be great. On the other hand, if there's an svn command that already performs this behavior, that would be great, too.

Either actions that can be performed from the normal Linux command-line svn client or from TortoiseSVN on Windows would be fine (or even a combination of them, if necessary,) as I have both available.

In case it isn't obvious, the directory tree involved is huge and I don't wish to manually perform the above sequence on each individual file.

---

What I've already tried:

I've already tried checking in both code trees as separate branches and then using TortoiseSVN's "Merge two different trees" option to merge the branch containing the newer code into a working copy of the branch containing the older code. While this did result in the branch being updated to the newer code, Subversion treated this as just replacing the files, leaving no per-file revision history. That is, it treated it as if all of the old files were just deleted and the new ones added as separate files rather than updates to the existing ones (meaning that "show log" did not show specifically which files were modified and that "Diff with previous version" on any given file didn't work as desired in TortoiseSVN.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a job for TortoiseSVN's ["vendor branch here"](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#extlibs) feature.

First add and commit the contents of your first tar file. Extract the contents of your second tar file to some other directory. Right-click drag that folder into your working copy and choose "vendor branch here". This is designed primarily for 3rd-party code that you are tracking in your own repository, but it should work for your uses as well.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't previously aware of this feature. Actually tracking 3rd-party code in my own repo is exactly what I'm doing. I'll try this out Monday and accept then.

Comment: As an update, this worked. For anyone else trying this in the future, though, at least as of 1.8.10, you drag the new folder **into the folder it will replace** rather than into the folder that contains the folder it will replace, which seems unintuitive. Dragging a folder into the folder that will be its parent (as with normal copy semantics) instead simply deletes all of the contents of the folder, which doesn't seem like a terribly useful (or expected) behavior.